# What is the best way to work with PHP and MySQL in C#

Tags: c#, php, mysql

I'm building a simple application that requires login. At the moment I'm connecting to my database directly from my C# application however, the college network on which this will be used doesn't allow direct connections to MySQL for some reason. I decided to take a look at how I would do this from PHP instead. I've build a simple login form and tested it and it seems to work. However I have some questions and issues that need sorting out.

How would I first of all stop just anyone typing in the address of the PHP file and getting the data back?

Second, how will I be able to get multiple results back? Let's say I make a PHP file that gets all of the user's files and stores them in the C# application, how do I actually parse this from the PHP file?

Here is an example of a login.php file I would have on the server:

```
    <?php

include("connect.php");

$username = mysql_escape_string($_GET['username']);
$password = mysql_escape_string($_GET['password']);

$squery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$query = mysql_fetch_array($squery);
$rowcount = mysql_num_rows($squery);

if($rowcount == 1)
{
    if($password != $query['password'])
        echo'Password errata';
    else
        echo 'Login avvenuto';
}
else
    echo 'Account non registrato';

?>
```

And here is the code I'd use on C# to access the PHP file:

```
string Reply = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://127.0.0.1/ClipCloud.Service/account_auth/login.php?username=" + textBox1.Text + "&password=" + textBox2.Text);
            switch (Reply.ToLower())
            {
                case "account non registrato":
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Account not registered!");
                        break;
                    }
                case "password errata":
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Password error!");
                        break;
                    }
                case "login avvenuto":
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Login happened!");
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error with the remote server, please let try again later!");
                        break;
                    }
            }
```

Sorry if this question is a bit confusing, I basically just need to know how to correctly manipulate a database with PHP using C# with correct security in place.

Comment: if php can connect to mysql then c# will be able too and vice versa, this is XY problem

Comment: So you want to access the database on a server that runs PHP. So what you want is a webservice probably. Like a REST or SOAP Webservice. Search for those terms and how to build one with PHP/MySQL and then consume that service with C#

Comment: @Lashane: not necessarily. php might be running on the same server as mysql and connecting via a local socket, while c# is running remotely and would have to connect via tcp. not all mysql installs are set up for tcp connections.

Comment: Yeah basically, my server will run the PHP, I just want a safe and easy way to parse them in C#

Comment: I've got a possible solution, in process of writing it. Hope the question doesn't get closed before I post it lol.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get C# communicating with PHP by implementing a simple JSON API Server.

Conside the following : *http://yoursite.com/api_server.php*

**api_server.php**

```
<?php

// Load Request
$api_method = isset($_POST['api_method']) ? $_POST['api_method'] : '';
$api_data = isset($_POST['api_data']) ? $_POST['api_data'] : '';

// Validate Request
if (empty($api_method) || empty($api_data)) {
    API_Response(true, 'Invalid Request');
}
if (!function_exists($api_method)) {
    API_Response(true, 'API Method Not Implemented');
}

// Call API Method
call_user_func($api_method, $api_data);

/* Helper Function */

function API_Response($isError, $errorMessage, $responseData = '')
{
    exit(json_encode(array(
        'IsError' => $isError,
        'ErrorMessage' => $errorMessage,
        'ResponseData' => $responseData
    )));
}

/* API Methods */

function loginUser($api_data)
{
    // Decode Login Data
    $login_data = json_decode($api_data);

    // Dummy Check
    if ($login_data->username == 'test' &&
        $login_data->password == '1234')
    {
        // Success
        API_Response(false, '', 'SUCCESS');
    }
    else
    {
        // Error
        API_Response(true, 'Invalid username and/or password.');
    }
}

?>
```

---

Then you communicate with it via C# like this, making POST Requests:

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    data["api_method"] = "loginUser";
    data["api_data"] = "{ \"username\":\"test\", \"password\":\"1234\" }";

    var responseBytes = wb.UploadValues(
        "http://yoursite.com/api_server.php", "POST", data);

    string responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(responseBytes);
}
```

Here, the `responseString` from the API server will the json string. To decode this, you can use this: http://james.newtonking.com/json

---

Here's a fully working example of how everything is put together in the C# app using a simple console app:

*Note how I am generating json string (for `api_data`) via the json library, instead of manually typing it.*

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TemplateFive
{
    public class API_Response
    {
        public bool IsError { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public string ResponseData { get; set; }
    }

    public class Login_Request
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // request params
            string apiUrl = "https://yoursite.com/api_server.php";
            string apiMethod = "loginUser";
            Login_Request myLogin_Request = new Login_Request()
            {
                username = "test",
                password = "1234"
            };

            // make http post request
            string response = Http.Post(apiUrl, new NameValueCollection()
            {
                { "api_method", apiMethod                                    },
                { "api_data",   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myLogin_Request) }
            });

            // decode json string to dto object
            API_Response r = 
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<API_Response>(response);

            // check response
            if (!r.IsError && r.ResponseData == "SUCCESS")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("login success");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("login error, reason is: {0}",
                    r.ErrorMessage);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public static class Http
    {
        public static String Post(string uri, NameValueCollection pairs)
        {
            byte[] response = null;
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                response = client.UploadValues(uri, pairs);
            }
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
        }
    }
}
```

---

finally, to secure the whole thing, run your site under SSL, so you'd access the api server via this URL: https://yoursite.com/api_server.php

---

Here's me testing the API server locally using a RESTClient pluggin on firefox.

- Success Scenario: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiEsW.png
- Error Scenario: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tMx4.png

Comment: I got an error: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<API_Response>(string, params Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: I believe I know what the problem is. `wb.UploadValues()` returns a byte array, where as `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<API_Response>()` is expecting a string. I am now updating my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this code I was trying to think of all different ways I would create an API, the API I want to use doesn't need to be used by anyone other than those using my application and the website its built on so this solution is quite clean for my needs on both the C# / PHP end

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is: remove the BOM :-)

```
   static class Http
{
    public static String Post(string uri, NameValueCollection pairs)
    {
        byte[] response = null;
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            response = client.UploadValues(uri, pairs);
        }
        string ret = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
        ret = ret.Trim(new char[] { '\uFEFF', '\u200B' });//removes the BOM 
        return ret;
    }
}
```